# Solve $y'''+y''+y'+y=\tan(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've been trying to solve:
$$y'''+y''+y'+y=\tan(x).$$
I tried to use variation of parameters, but stuck with very ugly integrals, that doesn't seem to be solvable?  Anyone has an idea how to solve it?
Obviously, the homogeneous solution is:
$$y=c_1e^{-x}+c_2\sin(x)+c_3\cos(x)$$

Comment: Hint: If $z=y'+y$  then the equation becomes $z''+z=\tan x$.

Comment: it doesn't look promising as we get $y''+y = c_2 sin(x) + c_1 cos(x) + cos(x) log(cos(x/2) - sin(x/2)) - cos(x) log(sin(x/2) + cos(x/2))$

Comment: Is your LHS in the comment  $y'+y$ or $y''+y$?

Comment: yes still can't solve it.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy the first one, tried to edit the comment, no success.

Comment: $y'+y=g(x)$ has a  simple solution using the  integrating factor $e^{x}$. But you may not be able to evaluate the integrals expilcitly.

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27%27%2By%27%27%2By%27%2By%3Dtan+x) can do it, but it's not pretty.

Comment: If you are looking for closed form, I guess it is hopeless, since the solution contains the integral $\int e^x \tan(x) \, {\rm d}x$ which is of hypergeometric type.

Comment: Okay, so you claim there is no closed solution for this ode? @Diger

Comment: unless you consider $_2F_1$ part of the "closed solution".

Comment: The method to proceed is set $z=y'+y$ so that you first solve $z''+z=\tan(x)$ with solution $$z=y'+y=c_1 \sin(x) + c_2 \cos(x) - \cos(x)\log\tan\left(\frac{x+\pi/2}{2}\right) \, .$$ This can be solved in full generality (textbook formula) leading to the integral for the last part $$\int e^x \cos(x) \log \tan\left(\frac{x+\pi/2}{2}\right) \, ,$$ which becomes $\int e^x \tan(x)$ after partial integration.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I followed your suggested hint, would it be appropriate to canonicolize it as a [matrix D.E.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_differential_equation),

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica can simplify the result a bit, but not too much

$$
-\left(\frac{1}{5}+\frac{i}{10}\right) e^{2 i x} \, _2F_1\left(1,1-\frac{i}{2};2-\frac{i}{2};-e^{2 i x}\right)+\frac{1}{2} i \, _2F_1\left(-\frac{i}{2},1;1-\frac{i}{2};-e^{2 i x}\right)+c_3 e^{-x}+c_1 \cos (x)+c_2 \sin (x)+\frac{1}{2} (\sin (x)+\cos (x)) \left(\log \left(\cos \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-\sin \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)-\log \left(\sin \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+\cos \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)\right)+\frac{1}{2}
$$

Comment: I don't really know from where to start, does it look familiar to someone?

Comment: Well if you need a proof, you can just take derivatives. Otherwise the computer result suggests maybe it is not worth trying to find a simpler solution.

Comment: how do you find this formula without "guessing"?

Comment: With Mathematica of course! 